# JSON.stringify does not convert arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

I know that I have gone about this the wrong way and very honestly it could be because I am handling the recursion incorrectly, but if so I am unsure where I have gone wrong. Here is the link to the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/eQEt3/21/).

Here is the JavaScript -

```
function propertyTest(currentObject, key) {
    for (var property in currentObject) {
        if (typeof currentObject[property] === "object") {
            propertyTest(currentObject[property], property);
        } else {
            // this is only to test the output
            $('#method1').append((property == 'value' && key ? key : property) + ' -- ' + currentObject[property] + '<br />');
            propertyKey = (property == 'value' && key ? key : property);
            propertyValue = currentObject[property];
            var arrayJSON = [];
            arrayJSON.push(propertyKey);
            arrayJSON.push(propertyValue);
        }
    }
    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(arrayJSON);
    console.log(JSONString);
    return JSONString;
}
```

Here is the original JSON -

```
var oarsObject = [{
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
    "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
    "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.50507158458214041
        },
        "longitude": {
            "value": -1.604064725846865
        },
        "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
    "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
    "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.50509265195620767
        },
        "longitude": {
            "value": -1.5961047836759397
        },
        "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
    "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
    "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.4963464715653228
        },
        "longitude": {
            "value": -1.5960947041991222
        },
        "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
    "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
    "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.49632551101280209
        },
        "longitude": {
            "value": -1.604015267530267
        },
        "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}]
```

The JSON is sent to the function as you would expect -

```
propertyTest(oarsObject);
```

Here is the evidence of where it goes off of the rails, a snippet from the console -

```
["latitude",0.5050715845821404]
["longitude",-1.604064725846865]
["height",0]
undefined
["positionReferenceType","geogWgs84"]
["latitude",0.5050926519562077]
["longitude",-1.5961047836759397]
["height",0]
undefined
```

Notice how the first two items do appear in the log initially and then only `positionReferenceType` thereafter. Also note the *undefined* JSON string. I'm sure this is because my recursion is wrong.

I'm aware that JavaScript arrays want numerical keys *after reading several other posts* but I am curious. `JSON.stringify()` seems to work on some of these and not the others. Furthermore the results are inconsistent, after the first round `positionReferenceType` does get stringified, albeit in what is apparently the wrong order (again, I am sure this is because my recursion effort is off).

The use case for this is two-fold. First we want to strip the unnecessary 'value' key of the original JSON that is being generated by a part of the system that we cannot modify at this point. Second, other parts of the system consumes the discrete smaller JSON bits  we would hope to output from a function like this. Output should be small, individual JSON strings (similar to what is being shown in the HTML output). ***The output should be a single JSON string, made up of individual key / value pairs as shown in the example below.***

```
[
    {
        "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851"
    },
    {
        "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84"
    },
    {
        "latitude": 0.5050715845821404
    },
    {
        "longitude": -1.604064725846865
    },
    {
        "height": 0
    }
]
```

I haven't even come close to the point of assembling the whole JSON string as I am stuck just trying to get the pairs out correctly.

I'm sure that I am overlooking something here. Should I create an object, instead of an array to get everything to stringify? Or is it something in my recursion tripping me up other than what I think are the obvious problems I've mentioned?

Comment: You're declaring the array such that it's only initialized in the `else` clause. Whenever you find an object and decide to recurse, "arrayJSON" will be `undefined`.

Comment: Also the console logging mechanism doesn't necessarily show array values the way you think it does.

Comment: Also note that because you *re-initialize* the array each time you put something in it, you only end up with one entry (at most).

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, declaring the array just inside of the for loop takes care of the *undefined* issue, but it doesn't take care of the stringify problem. Can you enlighten me on your second point? The console seems to be showing the arrays consistently for each item. Yes, the array needs to be re-initialized each time because of what we're doing with the JSON in the overall system.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is working fine, the problem is that the value you are giving it to stringify is not would you think it is/what it should be. you get `JSON string: undefined` because `arrayJSON` is undefined. It feels odd to me that the function doesn't return a value, and to have a recursive function that doesn't accumulate some value

Comment: you should state in the question what end result you're trying to achieve

Comment: `console.log("array: " + arrayJSON)` causes the array to first be converted to a string. The process for doing that is effectively `arrayJSON.join(",")`.

Comment: it's not really relevant, you could just as well do `console.log("array:", arrayJSON)` instead too

Comment: I meant, what exactly should the output look like... do you want to flatten the annoying value structure to `{"geogWgs84": {"longitude": -1.5960947041991222}}` ...or at the moment it seems you want everything as arrays of key, value pairs like `["geogWgs84", ["longitude", -1.5960947041991222]]` ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no. In `console.log("array: " + arrayJSON);` you are performing a **string concatenation** operation. The array is converted to a string before that `+` is evaluated.

Comment: You can change it to `console.log("array: " + JSON.stringify(arrayJSON));` if you want it to look like JSON.

Comment: I don't know, because what you're trying to achieve remains unclear.

Comment: Your code does not make much sense. What are you trying to do? Can you add the output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: See the edit @AlexanderO'Mara, the output should be JSON strings, each with a single key / value pair as shown in the example in the post.

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's nice. Do you want duplicate key/value pair?

Comment: Yes, duplicates are OK @Sheepy and I expect to get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, generally, two ways to recur and get a single, flattened array as result.

- First is pass the result array as a parameter, and each recur will add to it.
- Second is each call returns an array, which the upper level adds to its own result.

Either way, you need to test for Array subject first, and check for Object subject later, because Array is Object, and usually you will want to do different things for them.

Also, normally you will process the result (e.g. convert to JSON and then log) *outside* the recursion, to keep the recursion short and simple.

Here is an implementation using the first method, that includes JSON conversion at top level.
I have reused your variable name whenever possible.

```js
function propertyTest( currentObject, array, key ) {
   var result = array || [], o;

   if ( Array.isArray( currentObject ) ) {
      currentObject.forEach( function ( e ) { propertyTest( e, result ); } );

   } else if ( typeof ( currentObject ) === 'object' ) {

      if ( 'value' in currentObject && Object.keys( currentObject ).length === 1 ) {
         propertyTest( currentObject.value, result, key );

      } else {

         for ( var property in currentObject ) {
            propertyTest( currentObject[ property ], result, property );
         }

      }

   } else {
      result.push( o = {} );
      o[ key ] = currentObject;
   }

   return array === undefined ? JSON.stringify( result ) : result;
}

var oarsObject = [{
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
    "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
    "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.50507158458214041
        },
        "longitude": {
            "value": -1.604064725846865
        },
        "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
    "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
    "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.50509265195620767
        },
        "longitude": {
            "value": -1.5961047836759397
        },
        "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
    "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
    "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.4963464715653228
        },
        "longitude": {
            "value": -1.5960947041991222
        },
        "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
    "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
    "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.49632551101280209
        },
        "longitude": {
            "value": -1.604015267530267
        },
        "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}];

alert( propertyTest( oarsObject ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to scope the result array outside your recursive function as Sheepy stated.

Using `forEach` when it is an array value and `for` when it is an object of objects.  This way you are only processing a push of one object and not having to maintain the array.

### [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdy2m39s/)

```js
var arrayJSON = [];

function propertyTest(currentObject, key) {

    if (Array.isArray(currentObject)) {
        currentObject.forEach(propertyTest);
    } else {
        for (var returnKey in currentObject) {

            if (typeof currentObject[returnKey] === 'object') {
                propertyTest(currentObject[returnKey], returnKey);
            } else {
                var newKey = (returnKey === 'value' && key) ? key : returnKey;
                var newObj = {};
                newObj[newKey] = currentObject[returnKey];
                arrayJSON.push(newObj);

                $('#method1').append( newKey + ' -- ' + currentObject[returnKey] + '<br />');
            }
        }
    }
}

propertyTest(oarsObject);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayJSON););
```